# How to Update if the data exist else insert the new data (multiple rows)

Tags: php, sql, upsert

I need to create a insert and update statement, when today date is not in the database it will insert else it will update the QTY (from excel [this part I have done]) get from today.

But, there have a lots of row need to be insert and update.

1) it will check for the last 4 days in database, if there doesn't include today, it will just insert the data for today and update the last 3 days data. in the other hand, if there contain today it will just update.

P.S: I had try to use `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but it only 1 row affected.

If else statement , when i used this it only insert one row of data then the rest it just doing update.

Can give me some advise or example.

Comment: can you give us an example of how your table rows look like? I'm having a hard time understanding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you bulk copy your data from excel to a temporary table tbl and your actual table is tbl1 then do something like this

```
   begin transaction;
 if not exists(select * from tbl(updlock holdlock) where...)
begin
   insert into tbl1...
else
begin
   update tbl1...
end
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using to do this? I have done something similar in Ruby before. I would make the column (Date in your case) unique at the database level then simply try inserting each record. When I get an exception thrown because the Date is not unique I would then proceed to update the QTY.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article on mysql which says it supports multiple insert.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```

That statement is identical to the following two statements:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=3;
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=9;
```

So if we want to edit straight, we could do something like this.

```
INSERT INTO table (uniquekey,data) VALUES (1,2),(4,5)
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data=VALUES(data);
```